# Can Kohn anomaly be driven by parameters other than temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phase-transition, phonons

The Kohn anomaly is the singular behavior of phonon softening in materials, for which a mean-field theory is the BCS type and is usually described to be driven by lowering the temperature till some density wave order forms.

My question is the following. Are there any cases where such an anomaly can be driven by tuning some other parameters? Like an external magnetic field, pressure, etc. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yup! A quick search leads me to a 2007 PNAS paper titled "Unusual lattice dynamics of vanadium under high pressure." In this paper, they use first-principles calculations to study the (experimentally-observed!) pressure-induced structural phase transition in vanadium. They trace out the phonon softening as a function of pressure, and argue that it is due to the Kohn anomaly.